# Finding record with specific month

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

[image]

I am creating stored procedure with 4 input parameters (2* ID, year and month), that are being used in `WHERE` clause.

The problem is I just cant seem to write correct syntax for getting value (Koeficient) for a specific month in some period.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[obrPla_DohvatiPojedineRadniciKoeficientZaObracun]    
(
    @IDFirma INT,
    @IDRadnik INT, 
    @Godina SMALLINT,
    @Mjesec TINYINT
)
AS BEGIN

    SELECT rk.Koeficient       
    FROM RadniciKoeficient rk   
    WHERE rk.IDFirma = @IDFirma
        AND rk.IDRadnik = @IDRadnik
        AND DATEPART(yyyy, rk.DatumOd) = @Godina
        AND CASE WHEN rk.DatumDo IS NOT NULL
                THEN DATEPART(mm, rk.DatumOd) <= @Mjesec AND @Mjesec <= DATEPART(mm, rk.DatumDo)
                ELSE DATEPART(mm, rk.DatumOd) <= @Mjesec
            END

END
```

Comment: You can't expect people to help you unless you convey things clearly, can you?

Comment: what query do you have allready?

Comment: And Can you give an example of what the output should be

Comment: Output should be a decimal number. I attached a photo of a table, please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally,

I would advice you to drop parameters @Godina and @Mesec, and just go with single parameter like @Time ...

Then instead of checking for year and month ... because you are finding value that's between these 2 dates

```
DATEPART(yyyy, rk.DatumOd) = @Godina and 
    case when rk.DatumDo is not null then
        (DATEPART(mm, rk.DatumOd) <= @Mjesec and @Mjesec <= DATEPART(mm, rk.DatumDo))
        else (DATEPART(mm, rk.DatumOd) <= @Mjesec)
    end
```

Just go with

```
@Vreme between rk.DatumOd and ISNULL(rk.DatumDo, GetDate())
```

Comment: Nikakav problem ... uvek sam tu da pomognem :)

Comment: I jos nesto, baca mi exception "Incorrect syntax near '<'." za ovaj prvi prijedlog. To mi se desavalo i kad sam ja pokusavao sa case when...iskreno, nemam pojma zasto.

Comment: Iskreno nisam siguran da mozes da ubacis case u ceo where ... mislim da case mozes da koristis samo za neke vrednosti / promenljive ... ali ne i da zadas celu logiku where uslova, osim u slucaju da pravis dinamicki SQL (od nvarchar promenljive pa execute(@sql))

Comment: šteta, mislio sam da se case moze iskoristiti bas na taj nacin u where... ah, nema veze, ubacio sam ovaj between u proceduru, radi kao zmaj :) thx jos jednom

Comment: btw. slobodno mi reci kako da ti se javim ukoliko opet negdje zapnem :D (fejs ili nesto sl.)

Comment: Najbolje je ovde iskreno ... dok sam na poslu pratim ... pa naletecu na pitanje, i ovde dosta vise ljudi koji znaju bolje od mene :) imas vise sanse da dobijes odgovor